# Implementing Qt Gui on already running c++ console app

Tags: c++, qtgui

I have a running ATM console app and I want to modify it so that it has a GUI, using the Qt libraries.

I am trying to implement it without changing much of the code; rather, I want to call a widget where I was using `cout` or `cin`. But the problem is that when I run the console app, it just loads the forms and continues without letting me enter the required information. I hope this makes sense.

```
void ATM::authenticateUser()
{
    screen.displayMessage("\nPlease enter your account number: ");
    int accountNumber = keypad.getInput(); // input account number
    screen.displayMessage("\nEnter your PIN: "); // prompt for PIN
    int pin = keypad.getInput(); // input PIN
    system("clear");
    // set userAuthenticated to bool value returned by database
    userAuthenticated = bankDatabase.authenticateUser(accountNumber, pin);
    // check whether authentication succeeded
    if (userAuthenticated) {
        currentAccountNumber = accountNumber; // save user's account #
    } // end if
    else
        screen.displayMessageLine(
            "Invalid account number or PIN. Please try again.");
} // end function authenticateUser`
```

Comment: This sounds difficult. Console applications usually have a strict sequence of input, processing, output. Applications with graphical user interfaces usually allow "random access" to input fields which is implemented by an event driven system. If your appl. is separated into input part, processing part, and ouput part then it should be possible to "exchange" the input part by a Qt input dialog. Please, provide (not to large) sample code which reflects your current application. Then it should be possible to show where Qt may be added in (and how).

Comment: Thats the current set up of the console app code

Comment: May be, I misunderstood your question. A different approach would be, to write a Qt application which calls your console application (using `QProcess`), uses pipes (I/O re-direction) to feed your console application and to read output for display purposes.

Comment: Capitalized "I", added code formatting, reworded a little, broke text into 2 paragraphs.

Comment: On a side note, the code here is overcommented. You are just repeating what the code does. Comments should add information, not repeat it. This piece of code is easy to understand, there's no need to comment it. Especially "end if" looks really useless (it's a 3-lines block!).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very minimal but complete sample to provide "the idea":

```
// standard C++ header:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Qt header:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>

using namespace std;

bool evalInput(const string &account, const string &pin)
{
  cout << "Account: '" << account << "'" << endl;
  cout << "PIN:     '" << pin << "'" << endl;
  /// @todo process account
  /// @todo process PIN
  return false;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // main application
#undef qApp // undef macro qApp out of the way
  QApplication qApp(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  QGroupBox qBox;
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  QLabel qLblAccount(QString::fromLatin1("Account: "));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblAccount, 0, 0);
  QLineEdit qTxtAccount;
  qGrid.addWidget(&qTxtAccount, 0, 1);
  QLabel qLblPIN(QString::fromLatin1("PIN: "));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblPIN, 1, 0);
  QLineEdit qTxtPIN;
  qTxtPIN.setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
  qGrid.addWidget(&qTxtPIN, 1, 1);
  QPushButton qBtn(QString::fromLatin1("Send"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qBtn, 2, 0, 1, 2);
  qBox.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWin.setCentralWidget(&qBox);
  qWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qBtn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&qTxtAccount, &qTxtPIN]() {
      if (!evalInput(
        qTxtAccount.text().toStdString(),
        qTxtPIN.text().toStdString())) {
        QMessageBox::warning(&qTxtAccount,
          QString::fromLatin1("Wrong Input"),
          QString::fromLatin1(
            "Invalid account number or PIN.\nPlease try again."),
          QMessageBox::Ok);
      }
      qTxtAccount.clear(); qTxtPIN.clear();
    });
  // run Qt application
  return qApp.exec();
}
```

Qt has a nice online documentation with an encompassing reference manual and some helpful examples: [Qt Widgets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets.html). I used the documentation to learn Qt and can really recommend it as a start point.

Note:

As you will see in the examples, Qt widgets are usually created by `new` instead of making them local variables as I did to keep code short.